# How to Insert last inserted id in another table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Table 1

```
 $tblename="Table_staff";
    $ob->insert_data($tblename,array("username" => $staffmail, "name" => $staffname,"address" => $staffadrs, "email" => $staffmail));
```

Table 2

```
$tblename="users";
$ob->insert_data($tblename,array("user_name" => $staffmail, "password" => $staffphone,"name" => $staffname, "staff_id" => "First table ID"));
```

This is my insert function

```
public function insert_data($table, $array)
     {
         $fields=array_keys($array);
         $values=array_values($array);
         $fieldlist=implode(',', $fields); 
         $qs=str_repeat("?,",count($fields)-1);
         $ssQuery = $this->conn->prepare("insert into $table(" .$fieldlist . ") values (${qs}?)");
         $ssQuery->execute($values);
         $insid=$this->conn->lastInsertId();

     }
```

I insert some values in first table ... in second table 'staff_id' here insert first table id how to solve this problem 
 help me please..

Comment: Warning! Your function is [essentially prone to SQL injection!](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/lame_update)

Comment: How about returning last inserted ID in function `insert_data`?

Answer (score -1):

Use a parameter `$getLastId`  to return last inserted id and pas it to the next array to insert.

```
public function insert_data($table, $array,$getLastId = false)
         {
             $fields=array_keys($array);
             $values=array_values($array);
             $fieldlist=implode(',', $fields); 
             $qs=str_repeat("?,",count($fields)-1);
             $ssQuery = $this->conn->prepare("insert into $table(" .$fieldlist . ") values (${qs}?)");
             $ssQuery->execute($values);
             if($getLastId == true){
                return $insid=$this->conn->lastInsertId();
             }else{
                return true;
             }
         }
```

Table 1

```
 $tblename="Table_staff";
    $staff_id =     $ob->insert_data($tblename,array("username" => $staffmail, "name" => $staffname,"address" => $staffadrs, "email" => $staffmail),true);
```

Table 2

```
$tblename="users";
$ob->insert_data($tblename,array("user_name" => $staffmail, "password" => $staffphone,"name" => $staffname, "staff_id" => $staff_id));
```

Comment: Why another parameter?

Comment: @YourCommonSense another parameter to check you want to return last insert id or not